# Возникает 415 ошибка при отправке json

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp, spring-mvc

контроллер:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/registration")
@ResponseBody
public String registration(@RequestBody UserDetails userDetails, BindingResult result) {
    validator.validate(userDetails, result);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }
    userDetailsService.save(userDetails);
    securityService.autoLogin(userDetails.getLogin(), userDetails.getPassword());
```

сам ajax:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#button').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/registration",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    login: $('#login').val(), password: $('#password').val(), confirmPassword: $('#confirmPassword').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val(), name: $('#name').val(), lastName: $('#lastName').val(), age: $('#age').val()
                }),
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    //TODO Доделать вернувшийся результат
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

зависимости джексона есть:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

В чём может быть проблема? Что означает ошибка я знаю она указывает, что сервер отказывается принять запрос, потому что формат содержимого не поддерживается сервером.(почему?)
Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_details", schema = "mydbtest")
public class UserDetails implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "login")
private String login;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "age")
private Integer age;

@Column(name = "role")
private String role;

@Transient
private String confirmPassword;
```

Comment: Покажите класс UserDetails

Comment: @ЭмЭрИкс_007 добавил

Comment: Нужны методы get/set

Comment: А блин у вас же еще один обьект (BindingResult) принимает.Его тоже надо отправлять.

Comment: @ЭмЭрИкс_007 `BindingResult` инжектится спрингом, не надо его отправлять.

Comment: аа.ая думал это созданный класс а не спринговский.

Comment: Для того, чтобы понять ошибку надо указывать стэктрейс.